# POST-ing data from a RESTful web service to a Microsoft Azure Database

Tags: java, database, azure, post

I have the following code to POST data to a database from a web service. I am using the RESTful web service and I am connecting to a Microsoft Azure Database. I get this error message on the server run mode ->'Resource not available". Can someone help me with this issue ?

```
@Path("/addcar/{CSID}/{PID}/{LicensePlateNumber}/{RegistrationNumber}/{CarModel}/{MakeYear}")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes (MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)

public String insertdata(@PathParam("CSID") String csid,
        @PathParam("PID") String pid,
        @PathParam("LicensePlateNumber") String lpn,
        @PathParam("RegistrationNumber") String rn,
        @PathParam("CarModel") String carmodel,
        @PathParam("MakeYear") String makeyear) throws ServletException,
        IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        PreparedStatement query = null;
        String myString = null;

        System.out.println(csid+ ","+ pid +","+lpn + ","+rn + ","+carmodel +","+ makeyear);

        //Car car = new Car();
        //car.newcar(csid, pid, lpn, rn, carmodel,makeyear);
           String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://nysj1rpznm.database.windows.net:1433;database=gparkdb;user=gpark@nysj1rpznm;password=Technology00000;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
           String USER = "gpark";
           String PASS = GlobalUtil.PASS; 
try{
          //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
          Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

          //STEP 3: Open a connection
          System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT into gpark_cars(CSID,PID,LicensePlateNumber,RegistrationNumber,CarModel,MakeYear) VALUES("+csid+""+ pid +""+ lpn+ ""+ rn+ ""+ carmodel+""+ makeyear+")";
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println(sql);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            conn.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
}
catch(SQLException se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
 }catch(Exception e){
    //Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
    //finally block used to close resources
    try{
       if(stmt!=null)
          stmt.close();
    }catch(SQLException se2){
    }// nothing we can do
    try{
       if(conn!=null)
          conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
       se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try
 }//end try
 return "Vehilce added";
 //System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you give some more context about when you see the error please?

Comment: @CaptainMan i get this error when i run the application on the server in Eclipse-> Run as -> Run on server

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /gPW/
type Status report
message /gPW/
description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Are you getting Method not Allowed or Resource not Available? If it's method not allowed, check the service actually accepts a POST, and not maybe a PUT?

Comment: @JPMoresmau i get requested resource is not available

Comment: Then update your question, in which you say you get Method not allowed. 404 means the url is not correct and the server does not know what to do with it.

Comment: @JPMoresmau yes sorry about that .. Done

Comment: Better explanation and cleanup